# reading date column from iphone call_history.db

Tags: iphone, sqlite

i need to read the date column from call_history.db . i opened it with  sqlite database browser. but i can't read it. because it says like "1303826968" about date column. how can read it or convert it in "real life"

Answer (score 4):

`1303826968` is the number of seconds since January 1, 1970.

```
NSDate *d = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1303826968];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", d);
// Will output: 2011-04-26 14:09:28 +0000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert unix epoch timestamps to local time at the SQLite prompt, too.

```
sqlite> select datetime(1303826968, 'unixepoch', 'localtime');
2011-04-26 10:09:28
```

Search [Date and Time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for the string "unix".